# netty slf logging init failed in android unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, netty

My android project using netty. my unit test failed because below code:

```
val byteBuf = Unpooled.buffer(256)
```

The exception is:

```
Reported exception:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ch.qos.logback.core.android.AndroidContextUtil.getMountedExternalStorageDirectoryPath(Unknown Source)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.android.AndroidContextUtil.setupProperties(Unknown Source)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(Unknown Source)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(Unknown Source)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:412)
    at io.netty.util.internal.logging.Slf4JLoggerFactory.<init>(Slf4JLoggerFactory.java:54)
    at io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory.newDefaultFactory(InternalLoggerFactory.java:41)
    at io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory.<clinit>(InternalLoggerFactory.java:34)
    at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.<clinit>(PlatformDependent.java:63)
    at io.netty.buffer.UnpooledByteBufAllocator.<clinit>(UnpooledByteBufAllocator.java:28)
    at io.netty.buffer.Unpooled.<clinit>(Unpooled.java:73)
```

Also try with mockito, with below code:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class Jt808AnnotationTest {

    @Mock
    lateinit var androidContextUtil: AndroidContextUtil

    @Test
    fun testWrite() {


        `when`(androidContextUtil.mountedExternalStorageDirectoryPath).thenReturn("/Users/doudou/")

        val byteBuf = Unpooled.buffer(256)
    }
```

still got exception:

```
Failed to instantiate [ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext]
Reported exception:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ch.qos.logback.core.android.AndroidContextUtil.getMountedExternalStorageDirectoryPath(Unknown Source)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.android.AndroidContextUtil.setupProperties(Unknown Source)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(Unknown Source)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(Unknown Source)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:412)
    at io.netty.util.internal.logging.Slf4JLoggerFactory.<init>(Slf4JLoggerFactory.java:54)
    at io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory.newDefaultFactory(InternalLoggerFactory.java:41)
    at io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory.<clinit>(InternalLoggerFactory.java:34)
    at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.<clinit>(PlatformDependent.java:63)
    at io.netty.buffer.UnpooledByteBufAllocator.<clinit>(UnpooledByteBufAllocator.java:28)
    at io.netty.buffer.Unpooled.<clinit>(Unpooled.java:73)
    at io.netty.util.internal.logging.Jt808AnnotationTest.testWrite(Jt808AnnotationTest.kt:81)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1$1.evaluate(DefaultInternalRunner.java:54)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:99)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:105)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:40)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 (file:/Users/doudou/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-all/4.0.33.Final/119a52dd0818028dfe9ac92471ecebf3038f5cca/netty-all-4.0.33.Final.jar) to field java.nio.Buffer.address
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Answer (score 0):

Above exception only show in console, but the test code still work continuely.